# Why isn't my else statement giving me the amount i need?

Tags: python, math

```
#User in puts money amount
money = float(input("How much money is in your account? "))

#User inputs price of item they would like to purchase
item = float(input("How much is the item you would like to purchase? "))

#Calculate Tax and Remainder
tax = item * 1.09
total = money - tax
moneyneeded = total 

if tax > item : print (f'You have {total} left')
else: print(f'You need {moneyneeded} more dollars to purchase this ')
```

The else statement doesn't bring up the print statement that i wrote down, I expected it to write the print statement but instead it gives me the if statement (you have {total} left) and the amount i need in negative numbers

Comment: Look at how you compute `tax`; how could `tax > item` *ever* be false?

Comment: I think you meant to compare `tax` with `money`, not `item`.

Comment: you can also just check `if total >= 0:`

Comment: BTW, your logic will say you need more dollars if the amount is exactly equal to your money. It's important to remember the difference between `>` and `>=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#User in puts money amount
money = float(input("How much money is in your account? "))

#User inputs price of item they would like to purchase
item = float(input("How much is the item you would like to purchase? "))

#Calculate Tax and Remainder
total = item * 1.09
moneyneeded = money - total

if money > total : 
    print (f'You have {moneyneeded} left')
else: 
    print(f'You need {abs(moneyneeded)} more dollars to purchase this ')
```

---

```
How much money is in your account? 90
How much is the item you would like to purchase? 100
You need 19.000000000000014 more dollars to purchase this
```

---

```
How much money is in your account? 100
How much is the item you would like to purchase? 90
You have 1.8999999999999915 left
```

Comment: you're welcome @Hogaard

Answer (score 0):

tax = item * 1.09 so tax is always bigger than item

Because it can be negative u can use absolute value

moneyneeded = abs(total)

I think this works
if total > item : print (f'You have {total} left')
else: print(f'You need {moneyneeded} more dollars to purchase this ')

Answer (score 0):

check your if statement logic, I suppose you meant
'''
moneyneeded = abs(moneyneeded)

if money > item:
print(f'You have {total} left')
else:
print(f'You need {moneyneeded} more dollars to purchase this')
'''